# 'Procedure or Function has too many parameters specified'?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, stored-procedures

I have been searching the web for hours trying to figure out what is causing this exception, I feel like I am missing something...

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" 
        BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="ProductID"  
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
 GridLines="Vertical">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID"  
 InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID" 
 SortExpression="CategoryID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" 
  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ShortDescription" HeaderText="ShortDescription" 
SortExpression="ShortDescription" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LongDescription" HeaderText="LongDescription"  
SortExpression="LongDescription" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ImageUrl" HeaderText="ImageUrl" 
SortExpression="ImageUrl" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price"
 />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="CategoryID">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:s3435926ConnectionString %>"
         SelectCommand="SELECT [CategoryID], [Title] FROM [Category]">  
</asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ 
ConnectionStrings:s3435926ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SelectProductsWithParam" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
        UpdateCommand="UpdateProdsWithParam" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="DropDownList1" Name="prodID" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="prodID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CatID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="title" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Sdesc" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Ldesc" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="url" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="price" Type="Decimal" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The SP is

```
 [dbo].[UpdateProdsWithParam] @prodID int, @CatID int, @title nvarchar(50), 
                                            @Sdesc nvarchar(100), @Ldesc nvarchar(200), 
                                            @url nvarchar(50), @price money
AS
UPDATE Product
SET CategoryID = @CatID, Title = @title, 
ShortDescription = @Sdesc, LongDescription = @Ldesc, 
ImageUrl = @url, Price = @price
WHERE ProductID = @prodID
```

I am getting 'Procedure or Function has too many parameters specified'

Any suggestions?

Comment: I take it this is happening on Update, yes ? Can you open SQL Profiler and see what SQL is being sent to UpdateProdsWithParam ?

Answer (score 0):

Share your C# code. Error clearly says that you are passing too many parameters. Check out your parameters count & parameters name.